# How can I pin a specific folder to the taskbar in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.0, I could pin my Downloads folder to the taskbar by way of pinning Explorer to the taskbar, right-clicking the folder icon in the taskbar, right clicking File Explorer, and setting Start In to the Downloads path.

In Windows 8.1, Start In is no longer customizable. Is there another way to pin arbitrary folders to the taskbar?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this. but is the Target field customizable? if so, you can give it some arguments to achieve this. for example:

```
%windir%\explorer.exe "c:\users\Dave\Downloads"
```